# Facebook Login/Connect Window "Freezes" After Perrmissions Granted (XD PROXY)

Tags: jquery, facebook, forms, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

My website is: http://bit.ly/OF9NHS

On the optin box towards the lower half of the page, when I click on the Facebook Connect button and then login, it simply "hangs" with a blank window and does nothing.

How can I make it continue so it returns the users information to my form?

I've searched here but haven't found any solutions for my situation. 
Thank you :-)

Here's my code:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 /// facebook + optin box scripts
 /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '271302529636100', // App ID
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
      });
    };
    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
     }(document));



//           FB.init({ 
//              appId:'271302529636100', cookie:true, 
//              status:true, xfbml:true 
//           });
        function register_with_fb_222(){

            FB.login(function(response) {

            if (response.authResponse) {
                FB.api('/me', register_user_fb_222);

            } else {
                alert('You need to Grant Permission to Register with Facebook.')
            }

        }, {scope:'email,user_about_me'});

        }
        function register_user_fb_222(user){
            document.getElementById('name1').value=user.first_name;
            document.getElementById('email1').value=user.email;
            document.forms['mainForm1'].submit.click();

        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, once the problem is fixed, this question won't be relevant any more because the evidence of the problem will simply disappear.

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure I understand the comment... but I'd sure appreciate any help possible in solving this :-) I added my js code in case that helps. Thanks

Comment: What I meant was, don't just link to the site that needs fixing. Otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997/147645). Also, unless you have a specific reason for doing so, please do not use shortlinks. Nobody will click on them because they don't know where the link goes. You have 10k+ characters to state your question, there is no reason to use a shortlink.

Comment: For reference on shortlinks: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113658/147645

Comment: It's important that I have shortlinks because I do not want this help question appearing in search engines when my clients or their customers search for their domain name. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove

```
  <div id="fb-root" class=" fb_reset">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: -10000px; height: 0px; width: 0px; ">
      <div>
        <iframe id="fb_xdm_frame_http" name="fb_xdm_frame_http" src="http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=6#channel=f2929cfda&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hinsdalearearugcleaning.com&amp;channel_path=%2F%3Ffb_xd_fragment%23xd_sig%3Df30d8d28b%26&amp;transport=postmessage"></iframe>
        <iframe id="fb_xdm_frame_https" name="fb_xdm_frame_https" src="https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter.php?version=6#channel=f2929cfda&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.hinsdalearearugcleaning.com&amp;channel_path=%2F%3Ffb_xd_fragment%23xd_sig%3Df30d8d28b%26&amp;transport=postmessage"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

from your markup (which by the way is pretty extreme!), you are messing with the internal implementation details of the JS SDK...

That page is loading over 10MB of resources, with two of the PNG's being over 4MB each...

Comment: Thanks DUDE!!!!! That fixed it!! Now it works perfectly! :-)
Someone please UP this answer because I don't have enough reputation.